# Testing promise in solidity

Tags: solidity, truffle-test, mocha

```
}).then(assert.fail).catch (function(error){
      assert(error.message.indexOf('revert') >= 0,'msg.value must be less than tokens tokenAvaliable')
    })
```

I have the following code in the test file can anyone explain what is indexOf('revert') means

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it's not related to Ethereum. `indexOf` is a JavaScript function: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

Comment: What’s the question exactly? What is indexOf or why it’s looking for “revert”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `assert.fail()` throws an error, which is caught in the catch, and in the error message is the string `Expected revert not received`, which contains the substring `revert`.

In JavaScript console try the following:

```
console.log("Expected revert not received".indexOf('revert'))
```

You will get an answer 9.

Hope it helps!